# Identify events within a time window in R

Tags: r, events, time, identify

I need to identify a series (maximum 3 events) of events that occurred within 60 seconds.

Here there is the IN data

```
IN<-read.table(header = FALSE, text = "
2018-06-01_04:29:47
2018-06-01_05:44:41
2018-06-01_05:44:43
2018-06-01_05:44:45
2018-06-01_05:57:54
2018-06-01_05:57:56
2018-06-01_05:57:58
2018-06-01_08:10:35
2018-06-01_08:41:20
2018-06-01_08:41:22
2018-06-01_08:41:24
2018-06-01_08:52:01
2018-06-01_09:02:13
2018-06-01_09:22:45", quote="\n",col.names="time")

IN$time<-as.POSIXct(IN$time, "%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S",tz="")
```

and here there is the desired output

```
OUT<-read.table(header = FALSE, text = "
2018-06-01_04:29:47        1
2018-06-01_05:44:41        1
2018-06-01_05:44:43        2
2018-06-01_05:44:45        3
2018-06-01_05:57:54        1
2018-06-01_05:57:56        2
2018-06-01_05:57:58        3
2018-06-01_08:10:35        1
2018-06-01_08:41:20        1
2018-06-01_08:41:22        2
2018-06-01_08:41:24        3
2018-06-01_08:52:01        1
2018-06-01_09:02:13        1
2018-06-01_09:22:45        1
",quote="\n",col.names=c("time","response"))
```

I have searched for similar questions, but unsuccessfully. 
I guess that function diff is the first step for solving this problem,

```
response<-as.numeric(diff(IN$time)>60)
```

but than I have no idea how to proceed to get the desired output.

Any helps will be appreciated.

Comment: Why does it go from `3` to `1` in line 6?

Comment: uhm, I think that the response is right. Can you specify what is wrong?

Comment: I just can't understand the sequence: `1,1,2,3,1,...`

Comment: The responses are row numbers within the groups, it goes back down to `1` because `2018-06-01_05:57:54` is more than 60 seconds after `2018-06-01_05:44:41  `

Comment: @stefano To clarify: should the count simply reach a maximum of 3?

Comment: @Lyngbakr, yes maximum of 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using `dplyr`, `magrittr`, and `lubridate` packages.

```
IN<-read.table(header = FALSE, text = "2018-06-01_04:29:47
               2018-06-01_05:44:41
               2018-06-01_05:44:43
               2018-06-01_05:44:45
               2018-06-01_05:57:54
               2018-06-01_05:57:56
               2018-06-01_05:57:58
               2018-06-01_08:10:35
               2018-06-01_08:41:20
               2018-06-01_08:41:22
               2018-06-01_08:41:24
               2018-06-01_08:52:01
               2018-06-01_09:02:13
               2018-06-01_09:22:45", quote="\n",col.names="time")

IN$time<-as.POSIXct(IN$time, "%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S",tz="")
```

I've removed the blank first line of the input data frame, as it caused problems. The following function filters the data frame to those elements within 60 seconds before the given `ref_time` and counts the number of rows using `nrow`.

```
event_count <- function(ref_time){
  IN %>% filter(time %within% interval(ref_time - 60, ref_time)) %>% nrow
}
```

Here, I apply the function in a row-wise fashion, record the counts, and sort according to time. (Probably unnecessary...) The results are piped back in to the input data frame using the compound assignment pipe from `magrittr`.

```
IN %<>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(counts = event_count(time)) %>% 
  arrange(time)
```

Finally, the results.

```
# A tibble: 14 x 2
#    time                counts
#    <dttm>               <int>
# 1  2018-06-01 04:29:47      1
# 2  2018-06-01 05:44:41      1
# 3  2018-06-01 05:44:43      2
# 4  2018-06-01 05:44:45      3
# 5  2018-06-01 05:57:54      1
# 6  2018-06-01 05:57:56      2
# 7  2018-06-01 05:57:58      3
# 8  2018-06-01 08:10:35      1
# 9  2018-06-01 08:41:20      1
# 10 2018-06-01 08:41:22      2
# 11 2018-06-01 08:41:24      3
# 12 2018-06-01 08:52:01      1
# 13 2018-06-01 09:02:13      1
# 14 2018-06-01 09:22:45      1
```

I think what @PoGibas is alluding to is for some reason there are two entries with the time `2018-06-01 05:57:54` in the input data frame. I'm not sure where the second comes from...

---

EDIT: It's the new line in the read table that messes it up.

EDIT²: This returns a maximum of 3...

```
event_count <- function(ref_time){
  min(IN %>% filter(time %within% interval(ref_time - 60, ref_time)) %>% nrow, 3)
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this does it, as the count isn't reset when you go from line 4 to line 5

Comment: @zack Because there are two counts at `2018-06-01 05:57:54`, as I mentioned. When I run the given code two appear for some reason, although it clearly isn't in the data frame. Bizarre. Try running the `read.table` code... It's not just me, right?!

Comment: Ah, strange but i see what you're talking about.
I've never seen `rowwise()` before. Nice.
As a note, OP did say "maximum 3 events", so it may not completely answer the question, but it's certainly movement in the right direction

Comment: I got this error when running the code of @Lyngbakr: Error in c(1527820187, 1527824681, 1527824683, 1527824685, 1527825474,  : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'b' in selecting a method for function '%within%': Error in as.POSIXct.numeric(x, tz = tz) : 'origin' must be supplied

Comment: @stefano Weird. I just reran it with a fresh session (and relevant library calls at the beginning) and it worked fine. Do you have another package loaded with an `interval` function masking the one from `lubridate`?

Comment: @Lyngbakr, it is weird also because I have no idea where it comes from the first record in line 1 of the OUT when running the code. No idea, really!

Comment: @Lyngbakr, no other package loaded with interval function.

Comment: @stefano Can you try with a fresh, clean session and just the code above (+ the library calls)? Unfortunately, I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Lyngbakr. Solved, it was necessary to update the dplyr package. Very nice and elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a data frame with some edge cases:

```
IN<-read.table(header = FALSE, text = "2018-06-01_04:29:47
           2018-06-01_05:44:41
           2018-06-01_05:44:43
           2018-06-01_05:44:45
           2018-06-01_05:44:47
           2018-06-01_05:57:54
           2018-06-01_05:57:56
           2018-06-01_05:57:58
           2018-06-01_05:58:56
           2018-06-01_08:10:35
           2018-06-01_08:41:20
           2018-06-01_08:41:22
           2018-06-01_08:41:24
           2018-06-01_08:52:01
           2018-06-01_09:02:13
           2018-06-01_09:22:45", quote="\n",col.names="time")

IN$time<-as.POSIXct(IN$time, "%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S",tz="")

IN
                  time
1  2018-06-01 04:29:47
2  2018-06-01 05:44:41
3  2018-06-01 05:44:43
4  2018-06-01 05:44:45
5  2018-06-01 05:44:47
6  2018-06-01 05:57:54
7  2018-06-01 05:57:56
8  2018-06-01 05:57:58
9  2018-06-01 05:58:56
10 2018-06-01 08:10:35
11 2018-06-01 08:41:20
12 2018-06-01 08:41:22
13 2018-06-01 08:41:24
14 2018-06-01 08:52:01
15 2018-06-01 09:02:13
16 2018-06-01 09:22:45
```

You'll notice line `9` is a minute after the mid-group time but not the reference time. Line `5` is also the 4th member of what would be a group if there were no limits imposed.

Here's my solution using `dplyr`. I think it works generally speaking:

```
res <- IN %>% mutate(diffs = as.numeric(time - lag(time)),
                     helper1 = case_when(is.na(diffs) ~ 1,
                                         diffs <= 60 ~ 0 ,
                                         TRUE ~ 1),
                     grouper1 = cumsum(helper1)) %>%
  group_by(grouper1) %>%
  mutate(helper2 = cumsum(diffs) - first(diffs),
         helper3 = helper2 %/% 60,
         helper4 = helper1 + if_else(is.na(helper3), 0, helper3)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(grouper2 = cumsum(helper4)) %>%
  group_by(grouper2) %>%
  mutate(rn0 = row_number() - 1,
         grouper3 = rn0 %/% 3) %>%
  group_by(grouper2, grouper3) %>%
  mutate(count = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(time, count)
```

the result:

```
> res
# A tibble: 16 x 2
   time                count
   <dttm>              <int>
 1 2018-06-01 04:29:47     1
 2 2018-06-01 05:44:41     1
 3 2018-06-01 05:44:43     2
 4 2018-06-01 05:44:45     3
 5 2018-06-01 05:44:47     1
 6 2018-06-01 05:57:54     1
 7 2018-06-01 05:57:56     2
 8 2018-06-01 05:57:58     3
 9 2018-06-01 05:58:56     1
10 2018-06-01 08:10:35     1
11 2018-06-01 08:41:20     1
12 2018-06-01 08:41:22     2
13 2018-06-01 08:41:24     3
14 2018-06-01 08:52:01     1
15 2018-06-01 09:02:13     1
16 2018-06-01 09:22:45     1
```

I think i structured the `dplyr` calls in a way where you can follow them, but if you have questions feel free to post in comments.

Comment: I got this error when running your code Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : non trovo la funzione "case_when". No idea why I am getting this error.

Comment: is `dplyr` loaded? just making sure (i.e., `library(dplyr)`) - if it was, is it possible it's not up to date? `case_when` is from the `dplyr` library

Comment: yes loaded. May be the following objects masked are the culprits?> library(dplyr)

Attaching package: ‘dplyr’

The following object is masked from ‘package:stats’:

    filter

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

Comment: hmmm, try replacing `case_when` with `dplyr::case_when`